# PHP Class Value

Tags: php, fedex

I'm working on a PHP Class, one of the required fields for the Class is (`DropoffType`)
The answer to that is `REGULARPICKUP`.
Can I write this inside the class and put "=" to the `REGULARPICKUP`?

Example:

```
protected $DropoffType = 'REGULARPICKUP';
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $DropoffType = 'REGULARPICKUP';
}
```

or do it in the constructor (this depends on your specific case whether this is the way to go):

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $DropoffType;

    public function __construct($Dropofftype = 'REGULARPICKUP')
    {
        $this->DropoffType = $Dropofftype;
    }
}
```

Or if you have a set function:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $DropoffType;

    public function setDropoffType($Dropofftype = 'REGULARPICKUP')
    {
        $this->DropoffType = $Dropofftype;
    }
}
```